# gathering information from a txt file

Tags: java

File Roster: roster.txt

```
Reagan rebradshaw835
Ryley rbarber894
Peyton pstott885
Tyrese tmayo945
Caius ccharlton329
```

The program has to do with exception handling. Problem I am trying to overcome at the moment is being able to get the proper output. I don't know if there is a specific way to find the line that contains the name, and return everything in the line except the name.
so that we are able to return the username assigned.

For example, first line shows:

```
Reagan rebradshaw835
```

Method returns just `rebradshaw835`

Here is the code: (updated code)
vhthanh really helped me to understand how to read from a file!
I decided to edit the code using replace string commands. Without vhthanhI probably wouldn't have learned how to interact with the file.

```
    package chapter11;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LabProgram {
   
   public static String findID(String studentName, Scanner infoScnr) throws Exception {
    
       while (infoScnr.hasNextLine()) {
           
            String line = infoScnr.nextLine();
            //String[] values = line.split(" ", 2);
            
                        
            if (line.contains(studentName)) {
                
                line = line.replace(studentName + " ", "");
            
            return line;    
                
                
            }
               
               
           }
       
       throw new Exception ("Student ID not found for " + studentName);
        
        
       }
   
   public static String findName(String studentID, Scanner infoScnr) throws Exception {
       
       while (infoScnr.hasNextLine()) {
           
        String line = infoScnr.nextLine();
        //String[] values = line.split(" ", 2);
        
                    
        if (line.contains(studentID)) {
            
            line = line.replace(studentID + " ", "");
        
        return line;    
            
            
        }
           
           
       }
       
       throw new Exception ("Student name not found for " + studentID);
    
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      String studentName;
      String studentID;
      String studentInfoFileName;
      FileInputStream studentInfoStream = null;
      Scanner studentInfoScanner = null;
      
      // Read the text file name from user
      studentInfoFileName = scnr.next();

      // Open the text file
      studentInfoStream = new FileInputStream(studentInfoFileName);
      studentInfoScanner = new Scanner(studentInfoStream);
      
      // Read search option from user. 0: findID(), 1: findName()
      int userChoice = scnr.nextInt();

      // FIXME: findID() and findName() may throw an Exception.
      //        Insert a try/catch statement to catch the exception and output the exception message.
      try {
      if (userChoice == 0) {
         studentName = scnr.next();
         studentID = findID(studentName, studentInfoScanner);
         System.out.println(studentID);
      }
      else {
         studentID = scnr.next();
         studentName = findName(studentID, studentInfoScanner);
         System.out.println(studentName);
      }
      
      studentInfoStream.close(); 
      
      }
      
      
      catch (Exception exp) {
          
        System.out.println(exp.getMessage());  
      }
      
      
      
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the every single line from the `Scanner` and `split()` the string into an array of 2 values and then compare it.
Try this code:

```
public static String findID(String studentName, Scanner infoScnr) throws Exception {
    while (infoScnr.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = infoScnr.nextLine();
        String[] values = line.split(" ", 2);
        if (studentName != null && studentName.equals(values[0])) {
            return values[1];
        }
    }
    throw new Exception ("Student name not found for " + studentName);
}

public static String findName(String studentID, Scanner infoScnr) throws Exception {
    while (infoScnr.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = infoScnr.nextLine();
        String[] values = line.split(" ", 2);
        if (studentID != null && values.length > 1 && studentID.equals(values[1])) {
            return values[0];
        }
    }
    throw new Exception ("Student id not found for " + studentID);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain to me this code in the method more into depth if possible? 
I understand what you did but I am not acquainted with line split. I can see line.split" ", 2):, and I can see it splits the line up until there is a space in 2.

Comment: `line.split(" ", 2)` will split the line into an array with only 2 or less value with the space as delimiter. Ex: `Reagan rebradshaw835` will be split into an array of `Reagan` and `rebradshaw835`. `Reagan rebradshaw835 anotherspace` will be split into an array of of `Reagan` and `rebradshaw835 anotherspace` even if there's a space in `rebradshaw835 anotherspace`

Comment: For a quick explanation: `line = "Reagan rebradshaw835"`, with `String[] values = line.split(" ", 2);` we got `String[] values = {"Reagan", "rebradshaw835"}`

Comment: also I am having trouble with my exceptions.

Comment: public static String findID(String studentName, Scanner infoScnr) throws Exception {
 
    while (infoScnr.hasNextLine()) {
           String line = infoScnr.nextLine();
           String[] values = line.split(" ", 2);
           
           if (studentName != null && studentName.equals(values[0])) {
               return values[1];
           }
           
           if (studentName != null && !studentName.equals(values[0])) {
            
            throw new Exception ("Student name not found for " + studentName);  
            
           }
       }
       return null;

Comment: Replace the `return null;` (can not find by value) with the Exception, I edited the code above, check it again.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, you helped me figure out a way to interact with files. I'm afraid they didn't teach this to us in class. I never though to use a String array for this. Is there another method you would like to share?

Comment: just addressed the issue without using an array also!

Comment: I updated the code and used an alternate method based on what you taught me. The split method will be a tool I will have in my belt and without you I couldn't have done it.

Answer (score 0):

```
.split (" ")
```

for spacing

```
.split ("/n")
```

for new line (nextLine)

Comment: Thank you!!! I appreciate your help too. This is something new I been introduced to.